# Socket-transferred file: contents are empty

Tags: java, sockets, file-transfer, fileinputstream, fileoutputstream

I am working on transferring a file between two computers over a socket. Everything seems to work, but when I look at the contents of the retrieved file, it is empty. What am I doing wrong?

Here is my server-side code. The file foobar.txt exists, and its contents are "hello world!".

```
try{ 
    ServerSocket ssock = new ServerSocket(12345);
    Socket sock = ssock.accept();
    //here I get the filename from the client, but that works fine.
    File myFile = new File("foobar.txt");
    byte[] mybytearray = new byte[(int) myFile.length()];
    BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(myFile));
    bis.read(mybytearray, 0, mybytearray.length);
    OutputStream os = sock.getOutputStream();
    os.write(mybytearray, 0, mybytearray.length);
    os.flush();
    sock.close();
} catch (Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

And here is my client code:

```
try {
    Socket socket = new Socket(host, port);
    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
    out.print("get foobar.txt\r\n");
    out.flush();
    byte[] streamIn = new byte[1024];
    InputStream in = socket.getInputStream();
    FileOutputStream file_src = new FileOutputStream("foobar.txt"); 
    BufferedOutputStream file_writer = new BufferedOutputStream(file_src);
    int i;
    while ((i = in.read()) != -1) {
        file_writer.write(i);
    }
    file_writer.flush();
    file_writer.close();
    file_src.close();
    socket.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

**Solved**

Since I am using multiple threads and multiple sockets and testing all connections on one machine, I was simply running into a problem where the client (which has both the client and server code in it) would connect with itself instead of the other client. Changing the file transfer port for the different running clients got this all to work. Thanks for everyone who had a look at this and gave me some suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to what everyone else has said, you are ignoring the result of *bis.read().* It isn't guaranteed to fill the buffer. See the Javadoc.

The correct way to copy streams in Java, which you should use at both ends, is this:

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[8192]; // or whatever
int count;
while ((count = in.read(buffer)) > 0)
{
  out.write(buffer, 0, count);
}
```

Comment: Although this is the approach used in many examples, most of these don't discuss the buffer size, which was a problem I ran into when I first coded it up. This line: `byte[] mybytearray = new byte[(int) myFile.length()];` set the buffer size to exactly what I needed.

Comment: @Phil No. That doesn't 'set the buffer size to exactly what [you] need': you didn't need that specific buffer size at all. Buffer size is irrelevant: the code works with any buffer size. If the file is large your 'exact' buffer won't fit into memory; above 4GB you aren't getting the entire file into memory anyway; and read() isn't obliged to fill it in the first place. The `write()`s are only going into a socket send buffer, and from there into IP packets < the path MTU, and from there into a socket receiver buffer, so the buffer size you use here doesn't last beyond the `write()` call.

Comment: @Phil Yes, your buffer size shouldn't be the size of the file.  This is very inefficient because it requires that you store the entire file in memory.  Instead, you should send the data to the output stream *as you are reading if from the file*, by setting the buffer size to something smaller, like EJP's example shows.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you're closing the wrong socket on the client.  When you close the socket, you're closing the class field `this.socket` instead of the local variable `socket`.

Also, when you close the output stream to the file, you don't have to close both the `BufferedOutputStream` and the `FileOutputStream`.  The `FileOutputStream` is automatically closed when the `BufferedOutputStream` is closed.

One more thing---you don't have to flush an output stream before closing it.  When you call `close()` the stream is automatically flushed.

Comment: The `this.socket` part was a typo, which I have now fixed (modifying my code to just provide the method in question, I show a local variable socket above, whereas in my actual code, it is a global variable in a new class). I will try the other things now...

Comment: Thanks for the tip on removing some extra code. +1 for that. But I still am getting no file contents.

Comment: @Phil Also, on the server, you are not closing the `bis` or `os` streams.  I don't know if this will help in this situation, but it's good practice to *always* close your streams when you're done with them.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I think of that is that you actually never start receiving the file because the server-side doesn't read the command (`"get foobar.txt"`), so the client-side freezes on sending the command.

The existence of the file at the client-side might be from previous tests.

But, I'm not sure this is the problem. It's just a try to help.

Comment: It's a good thought, but I delete the file on the client before testing.